# Desktop Icon text too small

Tags: nautilus, icons, fonts, text, vmware-player

Hardware and host OS:
2017 Dell XPS 13 laptop with 13.3” QHD+ (3200 x 1800) display. The host OS is windows 10 home edition.

Problem: 
I have created a new Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop edition VM in vmware workstation 12 player. Post installation, the size of icon text on the desktop is very small and hard to read.

I installed the ubuntu tweak tool, which didnt help, since all it did was increase the font of everything else or title fonts rather than the actual icon text font. See snippet for a comparison of the normal font vs the other fonts in general.

I've looked through quite a few similar sort of issues on this forum, but none seem to be the same issue or the solutions for those didnt seem to work for me.

[image: Desktop snippet]

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu Tweak, or Unity Tweak Tool?

Comment: Sorry, meant the unity tweak tool.